# Best crawler to determine built with technologies?

Tags: web-crawler

Builtwith.com and similar services provide (for a fee) lists of domains built with specific technologies like SalesForce or NationBuilder. There are some technologies that I am interested in that builtwith does not scan for, probably because they are too small a market presence.

If we know certain signatures of pages that reveal a technology is used for a site, what is the best way to identify as many as possible of those sites? We expect there are 1000's, and we're interested in those in the top 10M sites by traffic. (We don't think the biggest sites use this technology.)

I have a list of open source webcrawlers - http://bigdata-madesimple.com/top-50-open-source-web-crawlers-for-data-mining/ - but my use case seems different than many of the regular criteria for crawlers as we just want to save 'hits' of domains with this signature. So we don't need to be fast, but we do need to check all pages of site till a hit is found, only use responsible crawling practices, etc. What's best?

Or instead of tweaking a crawler and running it is there a way to get Google or some other search engine to find page characteristics rather than user visible content that would be a better approach?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could tweak an open source web crawler indeed. The link you posted mentioned loads of resources but once you remove the ones that are not maintained and those which are not distributed, you won't be left with very many. By definition you don't know which sites contain the signatures you're looking for, so you'd have to get a list of the top 10M sites and crawl them, which is a substantial operation, but it is definitely doable with tools like Apache Nutch or [StormCrawler](http://stormcrawler.net/) (not listed in the link you posted) *[DISCLAIMER I am a committer on Nutch and the author of SC]*.

Another approach, which would be cheaper and quicker, would be to process the [CommonCrawl datasets](http://commoncrawl.org/). They provide large web crawl data on a monthly basis and do the work of crawling the web for you - including being polite etc... Of course, their datasets won't have a perfect coverage but this is as good as you'd get if you were to run the crawl yourself. It is also a good way of checking your initial assumptions and the code for detecting the signatures on very large data. I usually recommend processing CC before embarking on a web-size crawl. The CC website contains details on libraries and code to process it.

What most people do, including myself when I process CC for my clients, is to implement the processing with MapReduce and run it on AWS EMR. The cost depends on the complexity of the processing of course, but the hardware budget is usually in the hundreds of $.

Hope this helps

EDIT: [DZone](https://dzone.com/articles/need-billions-of-web-pages-dont-bother-crawling) have since republished one of my blog posts on using CommonCrawl.

Comment: The CommonCrawl datsets and example projects look like they may be what we need. I'll wait for other answers for a bit but will likely accept this one. Thanks for your open source contributions!

Comment: Unless you can catch the pages by [Google hacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_hacking), have a look at the examples mining Common Crawl for [RSS feeds](https://draft.li/blog/2016/03/21/rss-usage-on-the-web/) and [Wordpress themes](https://medium.com/@paulrim/mining-common-crawl-with-php-39e14082c55c).